# Can't configure C in Visual Studio Code, Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

Hi I am getting the following error when I try to run a simple Hello World code in VS code

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\nokni\FirstProgram\" && gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld && "c:\Users\nokni\FirstProgram\"HelloWorld
c:/users/nokni/new folder/library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find c:/users/nokni/new: No such file or directory
c:/users/nokni/new folder/library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find folder/library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The error seems to result from the space in the directory name `c:/users/nokni/new folder/...`. As a workaround you could use a directory path without spaces, e.g. `c:/users/nokni/new_folder/...`. Either rename the directory and adjust everything that references the old location or maybe reinstall `mingw-w64` and reconfigure VScode.

Comment: How could I change the directory path? Through environment variables?

Comment: Please run the commands `cd "c:\Users\nokni\FirstProgram\" && gcc HelloWorld.c -o HelloWorld` manually in a CMD window and show the output in your question. If you get a similar error message, then it seems to be a problem of `mingw-w64`. According to https://www.eclipse.org/4diac/documentation/html/installation/minGW.html and https://www.msys2.org/, the installation directory must not contain spaces and consist of ASCII characters only. As I don't know where references to the installation directory might be stored, I suggest to uninstall it and reinstall in a location like e.g. `C:\msys64`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what software exactly you have installed.

Comment: @Bodo The first suggestion worked! You can add this as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer

Comment: Please add details to your question what versions of VScode and mingw-w64 you installed, preferably with links. This site is not only to solve a problem for you personally, but also as a reference for others that may have a similar problem. Please clarify in a comment what "the first suggestion" refers to. Renaming the directory and adapting the configuration? Uninstalling and reinstalling mingw-w64?

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are clearly showing that they are expecting two locations:

`c:/users/nokni/new`
and
`folder/library/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o`

This should be very indicative that the folder "new folder" is not correctly recognised in the path. The directory name should have been properly escaped or embedded in quotes:

`"c:\users\nokni\new folder\library\mingw-w64\..etc.."`
or
`c:\users\nokni\"new folder"\library\mingw-w64\..etc..`

Comment: How could I change the directory path? Through environment variables?

Comment: @jokerp You should accept an answer only if it solves your problem.